# md-sidenav not working locally

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, node.js

I'm just getting started with pretty much everything front-end. I've got a sample project I'm working on with a concoction of angular/jade/stylus/etc.. I have a working example of my project below, on codepen, and an image of what it's *supposed* to look like (I think): 
[image: working version]
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWbjVY

However, if I run this locally I'm getting something different (firefox and chrome):

[image: local]

So, I'm not really sure what's going on. In the firefox debugger I see a lot of 404 not founds for the node_module/angular* scripts:

```
GET / 304 82.804 ms - -
GET /node_modules/angular/angular.js 404 1.848 ms - 44
GET /node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.js 404 1.500 ms - 54
GET /node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js 404 1.560 ms - 62
GET /css/index.css 304 0.495 ms - -
GET /node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.js 404 0.417 ms - 54
GET /node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js 404 0.479 ms - 62
```

.. I tried to fix that (not sure that it's even related) by adding this to my `server.js`

```
app.use(logger('dev'))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules')); // <-- this
```

But it didn't seem to fix anything. I'm not sure what to look at next.

Comment: Your concoction is missing Angular altogether. I'm surprised it renders anything at all. Fix those `404`s and everything will look/work as expected. Have you added angular to your node modules? Did you run `npm i` locally?

Comment: Angular exists in my `node_modules` for this project... `npm i` doesn't output anything.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your stack, but it looks like you're not requiring the modules correctly, since they exist in node modules. This is what you should look into.

Comment: Should the modules not exist in `node_modules`?

Comment: They should. That's where you're supposed to load them from. In module bundlers, such as webpack, they get required and packed in larger files (chunks) to optimize loading. However, I have no idea what you're using and how you're loading your assets. One thing is clear: they don't make it to your browser, and that's a major problem. What's the local path of your project? If it's `http://localhost/some-project`, have you tried loading `http://localhost/some-project/node_modules/angular/angular.js` in a browser? What do you get?

Comment: Yeah I've tried loading the path from the browser, and get the same `Cannot GET <file>`. My app is actually super small, so I uploaded the two main files here: https://gist.github.com/calebtote/0690a501ae0ab0cdf85e48cb9747fa83

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with jade. However, your problem seems to be quite simple. Is there a folder `node_modules` under root of your app? If not, find where it is and point all your loaders to that folder.

Comment: It is :(  http://imgur.com/a/4IQdl